# Prevent Maven from downloading remove repository

Tags: eclipse, maven

I would like to force maven to use my *local project in Eclipse* instead of downloading the dependency from the remote repository.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.github.gwtmaterialdesign</groupId>
    <artifactId>gwt-material-addins</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>
```

Please note that I only want *one particular* dependency to be used from my local source files.

Comment: Why? What problem do you want to resolve with doing this? What's your end-goal?

Comment: mvn clean install -o

Answer (score 0):

This command will build in offline mode:

```
mvn clean install -o
```